# How to create a photo slide-show in a PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help me out on how to put more than 1 picture in a `PictureBox` then show all the pictures one by one such that it looks like a small slide-show?

I am working on a project that needs me to show all my products on the form.

Comment: You should read the FAQ before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms since you want to use a PictureBox.

Easiest way is to just hold the images in a list and use a timer to update the PictureBox:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private images As New List(Of Image)
  Private index As Integer

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    images.Add(CreateImage(Color.Blue))
    images.Add(CreateImage(Color.Red))
    '// images.Add(Image.FromFile("c:\myimage.png")

    Timer1.Interval = 1000
    Timer1.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If images.Count > 0 Then
      If index >= images.Count Then
        index = 0
      End If
      PictureBox1.Image = images(index)
      index += 1
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Function CreateImage(ByVal whichColor As Color) As Image
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(64, 64)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp), _
          br As New SolidBrush(whichColor)
      g.Clear(Color.White)
      g.FillEllipse(br, New Rectangle(1, 1, 61, 61))
    End Using
    Return bmp
  End Function

End Class
```

The `CreateImage` function is just for demonstration.  You would replace that with an `Images.FromFile(...)` function call to load your own images.  Adjust the timer accordingly.